# OnKeyListener for dialog is not get called

Tags: android

My question is, OnKeyListener for dialog is not getting called when touch setting button of keyboard, but it's working well when touch on tab button, backward button.
So if you have any solution, it will be appriciable. thanks

dialog.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

```
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Log.d("", "on key press");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please share code, any example to show what u tried .

Answer (score 0):

When you press a button on the Keyboard that will affect your application, it will fire `OnKeyListener` event.

The setting button on the keyboards are only related to that keyboard and will not fire any event. This is impossible.

Comment: okay fine thanks Mr. tasomaniac. But how it will handle. Actually my application is of full window,hidden title bar app and when i'm tapping on this setting button,it opens input options and then there is no any back button. I want just back from this setting screen.

Comment: If there is no back button, this means that you are hiding the navigation bar. Navigation bar hiding is not recommended when the keyboard is present. You can un-hide it when the keyboard is open and hide it again when the keyboard is closed.